# Delimiting prenominal relative clauses

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

I encountered this sentence:

提供サービスごとの適切な値付けを行い、事業が継続的・発展的に拡大する戦略を立案する

Is there any way of knowing if this is

1. **提供サービスごとの適切な値付けを行い、事業が継続的・発展的に拡大する戦略**を立案する

or

2. 提供サービスごとの適切な値付けを行い、**事業が継続的・発展的に拡大する戦略**を立案する

?

Do I just have to rely on context?